# FancyBox Adding Extra Html

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I've downloaded the jQuery fancybox light box plugin for my gallery... I have a list of images in my database what I want is some extra space in the lightbox for comments descriptions etc!!
Here is my code:

```
$row1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload_data WHERE user='$user' AND ALBUM='$user_name'");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($row1)) {                
    $img=$row['FILE_NAME'];    
    $src='user_data/'.$img;
    $name=$row['ALBUM'];
    $id=$row['ID'];
    echo "<div style='display:none'>";
    echo "<div id='contet'>";        
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";      
    echo "<a  href='$src' class='fancybox' rel='gallery' data='$src' title='$user_name' id=''><img class='fadeto'src='$src'></a>";

    echo "";
    echo "<p>$user_name</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Here is what the jQuery looks like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();        
    });

</script>
```

What's holding me back is that I've successfully set up my gallery with fancybox. I can add some extra content but when I open it.. it only opens the first image and doesn't proceed to the next one.

Comment: the code is pulling images from a database then showing it ...all i want is to show comments descriptions for each image